# "Unsafe member access on an any value" TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3

I am new to VueJS and Typescript. I am playing around with Google Maps Javascript API and I get a Typescript error I dont understand.

Here is my code

```
<script lang="ts">

import { } from 'googlemaps';

export default {
  name: 'GoogleMap',
  data () {
    return{
      message: '',
      myCurrentLocation: 'unknown'
    }

  methods: {

...

    updateCurrentLocation(address:string){
      this.myCurrentLocation = address 
    }
```

The compiler throw an error at
**this.myCurrentLocation = address** and it says

> " Unsafe member access .myCurrentLocation on an any value."

When I hover my mouse around the this.myCurrentLocation in VSCode it incidates that **this.myCurrentLocation** is interpreted as an '**any**' value. Why is this happening? And how can I fix this.
I am using Quasar framework with Typescript. I believe it uses VueJS 3

Comment: The reason it has marked the `myCurrentLocation` value as an `any` type is because you have not typed the response object.

Comment: @shn - In my code's logic there is some processing done and then the updateCurrentLocation function is called which in turn updates a property.   How can I fix it?