# Typescript unsafe member access error in Vue when referring to property using "this."

Tags: vue.js, typescript-eslint

I get the above error when I refer to a property in the method section using "this."

I had previously posted a more specific version of this error.
["Unsafe member access on an any value" TypeScript error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955565/unsafe-member-access-on-an-any-value-typescript-error)
I thought I would repost since I am getting this error for all properties that I have defined.

```
=== This is my vue file =====
<script lang="ts">
export default {
name: 'Componentname',
data () {
    return{
      message: 'initial value',
    }
}


methods: {
    samplefunction () {
        this.message = 'hello world'
    }
   
}
====================
```

When I run this, or some reason typescript is not able to detect that message is a string  and gives me the following error at the highlighted line

> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access: Unsafe member access
> .message on an any value.

So my understanding is that TypeScript understand that from "*message: 'initial value'* " that it message is of string type. In fact when I hover my mouse over it, it does show that its identified as a string type. No matter what I do if I use **this.message** in any of the methods, the error occurs. In fact for all the properties that I defined, I get the error when I use "**this.propertyname**" The astonishing thing is that the code works perfectly fine and I don't see any errors or warning in the console.

Comment: Are you using Vue 2 or 3?

Comment: hi @Daniel_Knights , I am using Quasar Framework and it uses Vue3

Comment: Have you wrapped your components in `defineComponent`?

Comment: hi @Daniel_Knights - no I havent. I just updated the question to reflect this part of the code. Basically, its just <script lang="ts">
export default {
name: 'Componentname',
data ()

Comment: That could be why. Try: `import { defineComponent } from 'vue'` and wrap your component logic: `export default defineComponent({ ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is too late.

Aren't you missing the typing?

```
data(): { message: string } {
    return {
        message: 'initial value',
    };
},
```

The same goes for the method.

```
samplefunction(): void {
    this.message = 'hello world'
}
```